# Rails/Rspec respond_to a method_missing lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I know some of you are already doubting my sanity with this. I have a `ActiveRecord` class that uses method missing to dig inside a JSON attribute it has.

```
  # app/models/request_interactor.rb

  ...

  def method_missing(method_sym, *arguments, &block)
    return self.request_params[method_sym.to_s] if self.request_params[method_sym.to_s]
    super
  end
```

the test looks like this

```
before(:each) do
  @ri = RequestInteractor.create(result: {magic_school: true, magic_learnt: 'all things magical'}, request_params: {application_id: 34, school_id: 20, school_name: 'Hogwarts', course_name: 'Defence against the Dark Arts.'})
end

it 'should respond to attributes set in the request parameters' do
  expect(@ri).to respond_to(:school_name)
  expect(@ri.school_name).to eq('Hogwarts')
end
```

I tried binding inside the test, the `@ri.school_name` will eq `'Hogwarts'`, but when it runs the `responds_to` it will fail saying there is no such a method! The dirty, dirty liar!

I tried doing something like this in the model:

```
def respond_to?(method, include_private = false)
  super || self.respond_to?(method, include_private)
end
```

But this will return a stack level too deep, because of recursion, because of recursion.. so now the fate of my day is in your hands! Enlighten me O' great ones. how would I test the respond to of the method missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`respond_to_missing`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-respond_to_missing-3F). More infos [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/always-define-respond-to-missing-when-overriding).

Now, with all this being said. Your pattern will still look hackish if you ask me.

**Refactors**

Ruby has tons of way to clean this.

1. Use a delegation pattern

   `delegate :method_name, :to => :request_params`

   (check other options in doc). This should solve your problems by having a method in your object so `respond_to?` will work and you will avoid overriding `method_missing`.
2. Generate your access methods when setting `request_params` (meta-programming your accessors).
3. Use [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) since these can be initialized with a `Hash` such as your `request_params`. If you add delegation on top, you should be cool.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey @muichkine Thanks for your suggestions, I didn't think about using the delegation pattern, I really like it! the only reservation I have using that is that the `request_params` is a JSON object so it's going to have to access this as if it is a hash. So perhaps leaving method missing and then using the delegate pattern to provide a hook for the respond to. The request params are set assigned to the object early on and the RI object is only saved much later on so I would have to use a `before_save` filter to meta the accessors. Let me try the delegation pattern it looks like the best :) TY